# Alternative to operand && (C#)

Tags: c#, operands

so I'm trying to make a code with &&. However, when I put that in, it said that I couldn't apply the operand to it.

In specific, it reads: Operator "&&" cannot be applied to operands of type 'Server.Enums.PokemonType' and 'Server.Enums.PokemonType'

However, I need to be able to link these two things so I can make the code be two `PokemonType`s. So is there any alternative or work-around for not being able to use &&?

If you need it, this is my code:

```
case 225: 
{
    //Flying Press -- INCOMPLETE, needs Flying-type
    setup.Move.Element = Enums.PokemonType.Fighting && setup.Move.Element = Enums.PokemonType.Flying;
    if (setup.Defender.VolatileStatus.GetStatus("Minimize") != null) 
    {
        setup.Multiplier *= 2;
        setup.Move.Accuracy = -1;
    }
}
break;
```

Comment: That's not how types and operators work.  You need either a collection or a bitmask.

Comment: I think you're probably trying to do the following: `setup.Move.Element = Enums.PokemonType.Fighting | Enums.PokemonType.Flying;` That would set both `Fighting` and `Flying`.

Comment: You will have to change your enum to have the cominations too, the point of an enum is that it is enumerable, and that only one value can be used by a property at a time

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: you need `==` instead of `=`. The single equals is doing assignment, not boolean comparison, and `&&` is expecting booleans on both sides

Comment: What are you expecting the line starting `setup.Move.Element = ...` to do exactly?

Comment: @mhodges they aren't doing a comparison, they are trying to set the enum to two values at once

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre except ones which use `[Flags]`

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre Ah, that makes sense. I misunderstood the wording of the question, thank you.

Comment: also read up how how to construct a proper `switch(){ case : }` statement as well as where the `break;` goes

Comment: @MordechayS I'm trying to make this case be both flying and fighting-type.

Comment: @MethodMan that all is good. I just didn't include that bit because it's highly irrelevant. Thank you for the concern, though.

Comment: @mhodges Got an error with that. They aren't booleans, though, so no wonder.

Comment: @GlorianOakenfoot The code... half-works? It's not being super-effective on Normal-types like it should be, but is strong against Grass-types, but weak to Poison-types. I'm not sure why this is happening @__@

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system defined `&&` operator only supports boolean operands.  The `&` operator will work for enums (because it also works on all integer types, which the enums are based on).  Of course, if you want an enum that represents the combination of two flag values then you'll want to OR them together (using `|`), not AND them together.

Comment: I did that, but now I'm getting an error that says "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property, or indexer". Would you mind explaining what this means? ^^; But yes, I'm trying to combine the enums. Make them both apply to this case. The move "Flying Press" is both Fighting and Flying-type, so I'm trying to work out how I'd do that.

Comment: @Foxwells That means you're trying to assign a value to something that cannot have a value assigned to it.

Comment: Ah... Makes sense. I tried what someone else said (which is what I think you described) and did `setup.Move.Element = Enums.PokemonType.Fighting | Enums.PokemonType.Flying;`, but I don't think it's working right. It's not super-effective on Normal-types, but is not very effective on Poison-types. But it's also super-effective on a Grass/Flying type @__@ It's very odd.

Comment: Update: It's now being super-effective on Fairy types. So I haaaave no idea what it's doing anymore. It's doing its best @Servy

Answer (score 3):

To add multiple values to a enum variable you need to declare the enum with `[Flags]` attribute.

So your enum would be:

```
[Flags]
public enum PokemonType
{
    Fighting = 1 << 0,
    Flying = 1 << 1,
    Normal = 1 << 2,
    Dragon = 1 << 3,
}
```

[Define enumeration constants in powers of two](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), that is, 1, 2, 4, 8, and so on. This means the individual flags in combined enumeration constants do not overlap

Then assign using `Enums.PokemonType.Fighting | Enums.PokemonType.Flying` so it is possible to track all values assigned to it later.

Comment: You do not need to use the `Flags` attribute.  It's *nice*, and it will help some of the enum helper methods work better, but it's not strictly necessary.  All that's *necessary* is for every enum value to be a power of two.

Comment: I uh... have no idea what this means but it didn't work.

Comment: @Foxwells perhaps you need to go back and learn some basics as well as do some research on what it is that you don't understand this is pretty straight forward answer btw

Comment: @MethodMan I have had literally no official C# learning. My only experience is a buggy, poorly written code made by 4 people whose only prior experience was Eclipse. Apologies that I don't know understand everything you say, regardless of how "basic" or "straight forward" something is.

Comment: this is what the internet is there for so regardless I am just saying there are a ton of free resources out there especially ones that deal with C# Basics for Beginners, etc...

Comment: @Foxwells try checking enum flags documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx look at the examples and try it out...